# какой лучше выбрать синтаксис/язык для описания выражений с множествами

Tags: c#, валидация

Есть множество коллекций с уникальным именем , у каждого объекта коллекции есть формализованные поля. Получается что каждая коллекция по сути таблица с определенными полями.

```
 var collections = new Dictionary<string, IList<object>> // множество именованных коллекций
 collections['A'].Add( new BusinessObject(){ Item1 = "1", Item2="One" }
 collections['A'].Add( new BusinessObject(){ Item1 = "2", Item2="Two" }

 collections['B'].Add( new BusinessObject2(){ Field1 = "11", Field2="One" }
 collections['B'].Add( new BusinessObject2(){ Field1 = "21", Field2="Two" }
```

И нужно сделать определенные правила проверок корректности данных множеств.
например 
1. Все Item2 в коллекциях A, и Field2 B, должны быть уникальны 
2. Item2 присутствующий в коллекции A должен существовать в коллекции B как Field2

Данные правила должны описываться отдельно, чтобы не требовалась перекомпиляция программы при их изменении

Можно придумать для этого различные синтаксисы, например "CheckUnique, A.Item2" - "AllExists, A.Item2, B.Item2", где CheckUnique, AllExists это заранее запрограммированные операции. 
Но в приведенном примере если например потребуется сделать тоже самое но с условием Not уже нужно будет делать новые операции CheckNotUnique и т.п.

Поэтому хотелось бы взять готовое решение, для работы с подобными множествами, которое бы удобно интегрировалось c c#. Т.е. есть Dictionary>  его мэпим в какую-то среду которая умеет выполнять различные выражения и выдавать на выход результат.

Подскажите какие решения стоит покопать

Comment: Последнее время много говорят про R https://www.r-project.org/ Может есть смысл взглянуть.

Comment: Нашел вот такое решение https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/
из примеров

        `query = "Products.Where(Product => (Product.CategoryID = 3 And Product.UnitPrice > 10)).OrderBy(Product=>(Product.SupplierID)).Take(3).Union(Products.Where(Product => (Product.CategoryID = 4 And Product.UnitPrice > 3)).OrderBy(Product=>(Product.SupplierID)).Take(2))";
            expression = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.Parse(typeof(IQueryable<Product>), query, new[] { externals });
            result = queryableData.Provider.CreateQuery<Product>(expression);`